# Authenticate JWT with Guardian 1 and Phoenix 1.3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

Ive made a project that can be found here:

https://github.com/rootkc/phx_auth_api

When I try to post to:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4000/api/login
```

with the body:

```
{ "user": { "username": "kenneth", "password": "kenneth" } }
```

That is a user that is in the database.
I get the response:

```
{
"data": {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxM[...]gbPVHTsSvrCA"
}
```

}

When i then put that token in the header:
`Àuthorization: :token`
of the call `http://0.0.0.0:4000/api/users` that has the Guardian pipeline plug
I get back the message: unauthenticated

And i have no idea, what i'm doing wrong. This is my first real Phoenix project and i tried to follow various guide but the `{:guardian, "~> 1.0-beta"}` seems to be quite new, with bad documentation.

Comment: Since there is an open issue i guess i'm not blaming anyone: https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/issues/386.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial that is exactly for this topic (PHX 1.3, Guardian 1): https://medium.com/@tylerpachal/session-authentication-example-for-phoenix-1-3-using-guardian-1-0-beta-a228c78478e6

Comment: I did look alot at your article - but that is not for API authentication. But i got it to!

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference if you are authenticating API requests or not.  Everything comes in through a pipeline and can have rules on that pipeline.  Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 1):

Believe or not, but Guardian is very well documented library and it's very popular for Elixir and Phoenix projects.

Please check [this article](http://blog.overstuffedgorilla.com/simple-guardian-api-authentication/) for simple API authentication.

How exactly you wanted to put the `header`? You should use Guardian's already defined functions.

[Guardian.encode_and_sign](https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/Guardian.html#encode_and_sign/1) returns you {:ok, token, map} and you need this token to be passed to the header. 
Then, guardian uses plug [VerifyHeader](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/blob/b6ccd5d7d136bbafdf6166de7b45a2b8e0192500/lib/guardian/plug/verify_header.ex#L110) that expects token to be in form

```
Authorization: token
```

It's totally up to you how you want to mix up usage of guardian functions, but article from above is very nice introduction.

**Edit** 
Assuming that you are running [Elixir 1.5.x](http://elixir-lang.github.io/blog/2017/07/25/elixir-v1-5-0-released/), you can try to run your server in IEx and then debug what's going on: `iex -S mix phx.server`. Simply use `break! controller_name.action_name` and try to click this action in webbrowser / postman etc.

Also you can debug Guardian functions this way.

**Edit 2**

In [PhxAuthApi.Auth.Guardian](https://github.com/rootkc/phx_auth_api/blob/master/lib/phx_auth_api/auth/guardian.ex) you don't encode the token anywhere, but in [PhxAuthApi.Auth.Pipeline](https://github.com/rootkc/phx_auth_api/blob/master/lib/phx_auth_api/auth/pipeline.ex) you request that e.g. it has particular claims, but you didn't provide them.

You over engineered this auth by creating your custom modules that doesn't work properly.

Comment: I tried to follow this example https://github.com/oskar1233/texts/blob/master/Guardian1.0/Guardian.md provided in an open github issue on the Guardian page. But i encode the token using encode_and_sign in the SessionController. When i try to decode the JWT using https://jwt.io/ it has the payload "typ" => "access". So i guess when i call the pipeline with Authorization: token in the header. i guess that should work..

Comment: The article you linked is from 2015, hasn't Guardian changed a lot since then?

Comment: Also some of the things you linked are from 0.14 and OP specifically asked for Guardian 1.0

Answer (score 0):

you have this in your pipeline:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader, claims: %{"typ" => "access"}, realm: :none
```

which means your header needs to be:

```
Authorization: none: <token>
```

because that is what is in Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader:

```
def init(opts \\ %{}) do
  opts_map = Enum.into(opts, %{})
  realm = Map.get(opts_map, :realm)
  if realm do
    {:ok, reg} = Regex.compile("#{realm}\:?\s+(.*)$", "i")
    Map.put(opts_map, :realm_reg, reg)
  else
    opts_map
  end
end
```

my guess you need to remove `realm: :none` setting so your token can be properly parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I had an typo in my [Pipeline](https://github.com/rootkc/phx_auth_api/blob/master/lib/phx_auth_api/auth/pipeline.ex). Now everything works as expected.

Comment: this should be a comment.